# twitch.tv api- how to get logo of the streamer who is offline

Tags: twitch

twitch tv - how to get logo of the streamer who is offline?
For instance I can get logo link of the streamer like this(works only if the streamer online):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
getChannel("OgamingSC2");
});

 function getChannel(name){
 $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+name+"?callback=?",
 operateResults);
}

function operateResults(data){
console.log(data.stream.channel.logo)//logo   
}
```

But if the streamer offline:

```
data.stream
```

will be equal to null.

So how can I get the logo if the streamer offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, `stream` will be null if the stream is offline. You can use the [channels endpoint](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/channels.md#get-channelschannel) to get the logo of the broadcaster.